# Qt stylesheet breaks functionality of PyQt5 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

QPushButton click events aren't being triggered when using stylesheets, but are triggered when stylesheets aren't being used. For example, I can create a QPushButton and define a function to be called when the button is clicked like so:

```
self.scrape_btn = QPushButton('Scrape', self)
self.scrape_btn.clicked.connect(self.scrape_btn_callback)

def scrape_btn_callback(self):
    print("Scrape button has been clicked!")
```

Then I can set a stylesheet as follows:

```
# Set the stylesheet
base_path = QDir.currentPath()
relative_path = "/findface/components/ui/gui/css/style.qss"
full_path = base_path + relative_path
file = QFile(full_path)
file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
stream = QTextStream(file)
app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
```

scrape_btn_callback isn't called when a stylesheet is set, but is called when I comment out:

```
app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())
```

I'm using this stylesheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets/master/dark.qss but I've tried a few other stylesheets and experience the same problem regardless of the stylesheet in use.

I'm on macOS Catalina with all the latest updates. My python version is 3.7.7. PyQt5 version is 5.15.0. All help is appreciated.

To reproduce this problem:

graphical_user_interface.py:

```
import sys
from .main_window import MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QFile, QTextStream

class GraphicalUserInterface:
    def display(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        # Set the stylesheet
        base_path = QDir.currentPath()
        relative_path = "/findface/components/ui/gui/css/style.qss"
        full_path = base_path + relative_path
        file = QFile(full_path)
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stream = QTextStream(file)
        app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())

        window = MainWindow()
        window.initialize()
        window.showMaximized()
        
        return app.exec_()
```

main_window.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QTabWidget, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initialize(self):
        # Create sidebar buttons
        self.scrape_btn = QPushButton('Scrape', self)
        self.search_btn = QPushButton('Search', self)
        self.settings_btn = QPushButton('Settings', self)

        # 
        self.scrape_btn.clicked.connect(self.scrape_btn_callback)
        self.search_btn.clicked.connect(self.search_btn_callback)
        self.settings_btn.clicked.connect(self.settings_btn_callback)

        self.tab1 = self.scrape_tab()
        self.tab2 = self.search_tab()
        self.tab3 = self.settings_tab()

        left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        left_layout.addWidget(self.scrape_btn)
        left_layout.addWidget(self.search_btn)
        left_layout.addWidget(self.settings_btn)
        left_layout.addStretch(5)
        left_layout.setSpacing(20)
        left_widget = QWidget()
        left_widget.setLayout(left_layout)

        self.right_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.right_widget.tabBar().setObjectName("mainTab")

        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab1, '')
        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab2, '')
        self.right_widget.addTab(self.tab3, '')

        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.right_widget.setStyleSheet('''QTabBar::tab{width: 0; \
            height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}''')

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(left_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.right_widget)
        main_layout.setStretch(0, 40)
        main_layout.setStretch(1, 200)
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        self.setWindowTitle("FindFace")

    def scrape_btn_callback(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def search_btn_callback(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def settings_btn_callback(self):
        self.right_widget.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def scrape_tab(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('Scrape tab'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main

    def search_tab(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('Search tab'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main

    def settings_tab(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel('Settings tab'))
        main_layout.addStretch(5)
        main = QWidget()
        main.setLayout(main_layout)
        return main
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets/master/dark.qss - style.qss

Modify relative_path in graphical_user_interface.py to suit your environment. Create an instance of the GraphicalUserInterface class and call the display() method. Comment out "app.setStyleSheet(stream.readAll())" in graphical_user_interface.py to unset the stylesheet.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I think you should already know that the source code is important information so it should not depend on an external link since if it breaks then it will make it useless for future readers